# How to Update a dataframe column by taking value from another dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have two dataframes `df_1` and `df_2`:

```py
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    (1, '', '5647-0394'),
    (2, '', '6748-9384'),
    (3, '', '9485-9484')])
df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=['ID', 'UPDATED_MESSAGE', 'ZIP_CODE'])
# +---+---------------+---------+
# | ID|UPDATED_MESSAGE| ZIP_CODE|
# +---+---------------+---------+
# |  1|               |5647-0394|
# |  2|               |6748-9384|
# |  3|               |9485-9484|
# +---+---------------+---------+

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    ('JAMES', 'INDIA_WON', '6748-9384')])
df_2 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=['NAME', 'CODE', 'ADDRESS_CODE'])
# +-----+---------+------------+
# | NAME|     CODE|ADDRESS_CODE|
# +-----+---------+------------+
# |JAMES|INDIA_WON|   6748-9384|
# +-----+---------+------------+
```

I need to update `df_1` column 'UPDATED MESSAGE' with value 'INDIA_WON' from df_2 column 'CODE'. Currently the column "UPDATED_MESSAGE" is Null. I need to update every row with value as 'INDIA_WON', How can we do it in PySpark?
The condition here is if we find 'ADDRESS_CODE" value in `df_1` column "ZIP_CODE", we need to populate all the values in 'UPDATED_MESSAGE' = 'INDIA_WON'.

Comment: What is the relationship between this two dataframe? It seems that you just need to use `func.lit('INDIA_WON')`

Comment: No @JonathanLam, this is the manual way you are telling, what if the File got changed and update message also got changed

Comment: Then what is the relationship between df_1 and df_2?

Comment: I have edited the Question can you check once??

Comment: What if df_2 also has ADDRESS_CODE `5647-0394`? Then you will have 2 matches. Which one will you fill into df_1?

Comment: @ZygD no it will not be there df_2 is created by me only and here i am loading one value in ADDRESS_CODE

Comment: It is Simply like if ADDRESS_CODE column value from df_2 present in DF_1 Update df_1 column UPDATED_MESSAGE by taking value for CODE column of df_2 for all the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've interpreted what you need well. If yes, then your logic seems strange. It seems, that your tables are very small. Spark is the engine for big data (millions to billions of records). If your tables are small, consider doing things in Pandas.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_2 = df_2.groupBy('ADDRESS_CODE').agg(F.first('CODE').alias('CODE'))

df_joined = df_1.join(df_2, df_1.ZIP_CODE == df_2.ADDRESS_CODE, 'left')
df_filtered = df_joined.filter(~F.isnull('ADDRESS_CODE'))
if bool(df_filtered.head(1)):
    df_1 = df_1.withColumn('UPDATED_MESSAGE', F.lit(df_filtered.head()['CODE']))

df_1.show()
# +---+---------------+---------+
# | ID|UPDATED_MESSAGE| ZIP_CODE|
# +---+---------------+---------+
# |  1|      INDIA_WON|5647-0394|
# |  2|      INDIA_WON|6748-9384|
# |  3|      INDIA_WON|9485-9484|
# +---+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: Also, the output is wrong.  Only row two is a match in the zip code data set to the address (person) data set.

Comment: I've updated the answer so that it would work for Spark versions earlier than 3.3

Comment: hi @ZygD this one working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

The below Python method returns either an original `df_1` when no `ZIP_CODE` match has been found in `df_2` or an modified `df_1` where column `UPDATED_MESSAGE` is filled in with the value from `df_2.CODE` column:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

def update_df1(df_1, df_2):
    if (df_1.join(df_2, on=(col("ZIP_CODE") == col("ADDRESS_CODE")), how="inner").count() == 0):
        return df_1
    code = df_2.collect()[0]["CODE"]
    return df_1.withColumn("UPDATED_MESSAGE", lit(code))
    
update_df1(df_1, df_2).show()

+---+---------------+---------+
| ID|UPDATED_MESSAGE| ZIP_CODE|
+---+---------------+---------+
|  1|      INDIA_WON|5647-0394|
|  2|      INDIA_WON|6748-9384|
|  3|      INDIA_WON|9485-9484|
+---+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: The answer should be the address code in the update message.  See statement above.

Comment: You updated the message with the zip code.

Comment: The answer should be CODE in the UPDATED_MESSAGE, not the 'address code'. OPs explanation: "we need to populate all the values in 'UPDATED_MESSAGE' = 'INDIA_WON'". Please read the thread with understanding, before commenting and downvoting.

Comment: hi @BartoszGajda, Thanks for your answer your answer is also working for me . But i have already Ticked  answer because i have used that already but upvoting it for future reference who are looking for this type of solutions

Answer (score 0):

I propose use of broadcast join in this case to avoid excessive shuffle.

Code and logic below

```
new=(df_1.drop('UPDATED_MESSAGE').join(broadcast(df_2.drop('NAME')),how='left', on=df_1.ZIP_CODE==df_2.ADDRESS_CODE)#Drop the null column and join
     .drop('ADDRESS_CODE')#Drop column no longer neede
     .toDF('ID', 'ZIP_CODE', 'UPDATED_MESSAGE')#rename new df
    ).show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Why use dataframes when Spark SQL is so much easier?

Turn data frames into temporary views.

```
%python
df_1.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_zipcodes")
df_2.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_person")
```

Write simple Spark SQL to get answer.

```
%sql 
select 
  a.id, 
  case when b.code is null then '' else b.code end as update_message, 
  a.zip_code 
from tmp_zipcodes as a
left join tmp_person as b
on a.zip_code = b.address_code
```

Output from query.  Use spark.sql() to make an dataframe if you need to write to disk.

[image]

Overwrite whole data frame with new answer.

```
sql_txt = """
  select 
    a.id, 
    case when b.code is null then '' else b.code end as update_message, 
    a.zip_code 
  from tmp_zipcodes as a
  left join tmp_person as b
  on a.zip_code = b.address_code
"""
df_1 = spark.sql(sql_txt)
```

Comment: Hi @CRAFT DBA , i need to update all the rows of column 'UPDATEED_MESSAGE' with value as 'INDIA_WON'

Comment: The spark.sql () just creates another dataframe.  Just set it to the original.  Work with Spark SQL, it is so clean compared to the methods!!